# Thread safety with a linked list in C Socket Programming

Tags: multithreading, sockets, linked-list, thread-safety, pthreads

I am using threads and TCP to implement a P2P file transfer in C. I have a tracker, which keeps track of all of the peers who are connected to it. When a peer first connects, it sends its files from its current directory to the tracker who places all the peer's files in a shared linked list. Each peer has its own thread in the tracker and when a peer exits, the tracker closes that peer's connection and removes all of the files from that peer from the linked list. What I am concerned about is locking the linked list when nodes are being added and also deleted. I want to safely be able to make changes to the linked list from various threads. I have written my code to add/delete from my linked list and also search (not sure if I need to use locking when I search) How can I modify my code to ensure linked safety between the threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using mutexes to protect data or other resources from concurrent access.

In the context of POSIX Threads the `pthread_mutex_t` type (from [`sys/types.h`, The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)) is used for the mutexes.

`pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` functions ([The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)) can be used to protect the instance of linked-list type from concurrent access for both operations:

- read operation: when enumerating the list (i.e. reading `next` pointer) and using (reading/writing) the data being stored in the node;
- write operation: changing the node: both `next` pointer and the data being stored in the node.

Also, the same mutex can be used to protect access to the `head` [of the linked-list] pointer.

Example:

```c
// ...

pthread_mutex_t list_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// ...

void *peer_handler(void *p)
{
    // ...

    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);
    if (numNodes == 0) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail->next = NULL;
        numNodes++;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail->next = NULL;
        numNodes++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);

    // ...

    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);
    struct fileNode *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if ((strcmp(ptr->ip, temp_ip) == 0) && ptr->port == temp_port) {
            cmd = htonl(200);
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);

    // ...
}

void sendList(int newsockfd)
{
    // ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);
    struct fileNode *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        // ...

        ptr = ptr->next;

        // ...
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);
}

void removeFiles(uint32_t port, char *client_ip)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);

    // ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);
}

void print()
{
    // ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);
    struct fileNode *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        // ...

        ptr = ptr->next;

        // ...
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);
}
```

It is worth noting that reducing lock contention — an important part of performance tuning concurrent applications.

### Socket-related problems

The `send()` and `recv()` functions do not guarantee that **all the specified number of bytes** will be sent/received with one function call.

The appropriate loop should be used to send or receive **the required (expected) number of bytes**. For the additional details, please refer to the article: [TCP/IP client-server application: exchange with string messages](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/02/09/tcpip-client-server-application-exchange-with-string-messages/).

Also, be careful with such constructions:

```
n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); 
// ...
buffer[n] = '\0';
```

The expected number of bytes (or, in this case, characters) to be received should be `sizeof(buffer) - 1`. Otherwise, there is a data loss: the last character is overwritten with the terminating null character.

Comment: How does this know which list to lock?

Comment: @Rachelle, the mutex itself «does not know» which list to lock. **The use** (lock and unlock function calls) **of the mutex** for access to exactly one global instance of the linked-list type **«associates» the mutex** with the instance of the linked-list type.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to have one `pthread_mutex_t` that you lock before any access to the list, and unlock once finished.  Declare it alongside the list variables:

```
struct fileNode *head, *tail;
int numNodes = 0;
pthread_mutex_t list_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

eg. when adding a node:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
if (numNodes == 0) {
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    tail->next = NULL;
    numNodes++;
}
else {
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    tail->next = NULL;
    numNodes++;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
```

or when traversing the list:

```
//check if peer is in the file list
pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
ptr = head;
while(ptr != NULL) {
    // if peer is found
    if((strcmp(ptr->ip, temp_ip) == 0) && ptr->port == temp_port){
        cmd = htonl(200); //set cmd to 1
        break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);
```

Since your list is accessed relatively rarely, this should be fine.  If you run into scalability problems caused by contention on this lock, you can move to a more complicated locking scheme.

Comment: Thanks so much! how is it that I should declare &list_lock?

Comment: @Rachelle: I've added a bit to the start of the question to show where it should be declared.

Comment: When I implemented the locking, it affected my client/server and wouldn't let the server accept any clients. I'm getting in "invalid argument" error. I'm confused as to how this knows which list to lock.

Comment: @Rachelle: That sounds unrelated.  It doesn't *need* to know which list to lock - that's just a matter of some rules that you need to follow (always take the lock before accessing the list).